# import tensorflow failed, "ImportError: DLL load failed" even cpu version

Tags: windows, tensorflow

There is a history before this issue happens to me
1. I can use tensorflow cpu version at first
2. I want to speed up learning, so I installed tensorflow-gpu. But failed, the error is "DLL load failed".
3. After whole day troubleshooting..., I gave up finally.
4. I uninstall gpu version and install cpu version back. But the same failure is still there

Please advise~~

Answer (score 0):

As of April 2019, I solved the "DLL load failed" problem under Windows 10 / Python 3.6.x / GPU RTX 20xx by installing **CUDA 10.0** (not 10.1 or 9.x!!!) with **cuDNN 7.5.0**. I also have Visual Studio 2015 installed.

If you have CUDA 10.1, uninstall it, install 10.0, and reboot. Place the files from cuDNN in the respective dirs of your CUDA installation. Don't forget to add the location of your cuDNN `*.dll` files (the `/bin/` folder of your CUDA installation) to your PATH.

Tensorflow can be installed using `pip install tensorflow-gpu` (currently version 1.13.1).